von Neumann-Numbers in Second Order ZFC with Full Semantics - Eliminating Non-Standard-Numbers
The background:
In $ZFC$ the summary of the von Neumann numbers is not in every model a set, because $ZFC$ allows models, in which there are non-standard numbers that cannot be separated with FOL (First Order Language).
Using second order $ZFC\ $ ($=:ZFC_2$, that is replacing the axiom scheme of Replacement by a single axiom quantifying over all functions and the Separation axiom scheme by a single axiom quantifying over all predicates/subsets). I read that all models are isomorphic up to the number of strongly inaccessible cardinals when using "full second order semantics" (not Henkin).
My understanding was that in $ZFC_2$ with full semantic every summary/subcollection of arbitrary elements of a set $M$ is a set again and a subset of $M$. The domains for quantifying over all functions/predicates/subsets should be all possible "combinations of elements", I supposed that this is "full second order semantics". So the average of all inductive sets are just the von Neumann numbers without any non-standard numbers.
I think this understanding cannot be right, because otherwise we would not need the axiom of choice, the existence of a function of choice for a family of disjoint nonempty sets would always be provided by the full semantics (for every function $f$ can be described by a subset of $A\times B\ $ for $\ f:A\rightarrow B$).
My questions:

Is it correct that in $ZFC_2$ with full sematics the summary of the von Neumann numbers is always a set, and non-standard Numbers cannot appear there?
What is the mistake in my understanding concerning the axiom of choice?


It’s definitely true that the natural numbers are standard in any model of second order ZFC. I think it’s also true that any model of second order ZF satisfies choice (given the axiom of choice holds in the background) though there may be technicalities I’m overlooking. (More exactly, the models of second order ZF are just $V_{\kappa}$ for inaccessible $\kappa$, which would imply all of this, but I’m on the move and can’t collect the details of the quasi-categoricity proof concerning AC in my head.)

Note that you also need second-order powerset - not just stronger separation/replacement schemes. (But yes, @spaceisdarkgreen is right - choice is unnecessary. The proof is easy: any $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}2$ must be well-founded, so WLOG transitive, and now show by induction on $\alpha$ that if $\alpha<Ord^M$ then $V\alpha\subseteq M$. This last bit is where second-order powerset comes in: you need to argue that the thing $M$ thinks is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ actually is $\mathcal{P}(X)$, whenever $X\in M$.)

@NoahSchweber I think choice (as opposed to the full quasicategoricity result) follows just from 2nd order replacement though, right?

@spaceisdarkgreen Yes, that's right - the point is that choice sets are "small" (but powersets aren't) despite being complicated.

@NoahSchweber Do you know of any examples of models of ZFC + 2nd order replacement but not 2nd order power set?

@spaceisdarkgreen Take $H_{\omega_{17}}$, the point being that $\omega_{17}$ is regular but not a strong limit. (Or $V_\lambda$ for $\lambda$ a weak inaccessible $<2^{\aleph_0}$, which consistently exists.)

@NoahSchweber I meant still satisfying first order power set (so not the first one). Why does the second one satisfy (even first order) replacement?

@spaceisdarkgreen Sorry, the second one should be $H_\lambda$. Separately, I think second-order replacement + first-order powerset gives second-order powerset, so my initial comment was wrong. Not my day!

@NoahSchweber having a rough day too… right, makes sense.  Replacement implies every function whose domain is a set is itself a set (not just that its image is a set) so that gives full power sets from full replacement.

Your understanding is correct. The only thing wrong is your expectation that we shouldn't be able to get choice "for free".
This happens with full second-order logic, that set theoretical details from the metatheory wind up determining the logical consequences. For instance,  $\sf ZFC_2$ "decides the continuum hypothesis". Which way? Whichever way the background set-theoretical universe says, of course.
This is just a consequence of what is noted in the comments that the only models of $\sf ZFC_2$ (or $\sf ZF_2$) up to isomorphism are $V_\kappa$ for $\kappa$ inaccessible, so any statement that is only about sets of hereditary cardinality less than the first innacessible is fully determined by the background.
Similarly, since we pull in entire rank-initial segments into the model, that includes all the well-orderings for everything and we get choice. Your argument is more direct: second-order replacement just directly smuggles any choice function from the outside into the model.

I don't know anything about second-order logic, but re: "so any statement that is only about sets of hereditary cardinality less than the first innacessible is fully determined by the background" - aren't you appealing to some kind of completeness here? I was under the impression that second-order logic wasn't complete in this way.

@QiaochuYuan Yes, since there's no complete deductive system for second order logic, the relationship between semantic completeness and deductive completeness of a theory breaks down. The semantic completeness of a theory can be quite fantanstic (e.g. 2nd order $\sf PA$ is fully complete... what's more, it only has one model) whereas Gödel incompleteness always prohibits deductive completeness for in any effective sound deductive system you might try. I'm not appealing to completeness, I'm asserting (some amount of) semantic completeness.

@QiaochuYuan I guess I should be more explicit about what I mean by "decided by the background". I mean when we commit ourselves to a particular background model of set theory, we also get a decision on which one of the statement and negation is a semantic consequence (which in more proof theoretical terms just means the background set theory proves semantic completeness for that statement). Moreover, $\sf ZFC$ proves "$\sf CH$  implies $\sf \ulcorner ZFC_2\urcorner\models \ulcorner CH\urcorner$" and $\sf\lnot CH$ implies $\sf\ulcorner ZFC_2\urcorner\models \ulcorner\lnot CH\urcorner$."

@spaceisdarkgreen: Thanks a lot for your answer, that is very helpful for me. Your note "set theoretical details from the metatheory wind up determining the logical consequences" fills for me as a beginner in set-theory a gap of knowledge.

From the discussion with @NoahSchweber concerning the powerset-axiom I learned, that a second-order formulation of the powerset-axiom  is not necessary. With full semantics I can conclude that the von Neumann-Numbers form a set and choice functions always exist. Necessary is only second-order-Replacement (second-order-Sparation follows from this), the other axioms stay first order, AC can be omitted. Thanks to all commentators enriching the discussion concerning my questions.
